# Download jar using a url

Tags: java, deployment, jar

I have a huge project designed using javafx. I have made an executable jar out of it. That jar has to be used by people globally. So instead of giving that jar to everyone I want to create a link or an html page through which people can download this jar and install it to their system. 
I have no idea regarding the way I should execute it.
I tried running jar as webstart and in browser. Tried different ways of deploying javafx. But didn't get any output. Can anyone suggest me which direction shall I go. As I have no knowledge on this field. I just know basic java and javafx.
Any suggestion is appreciated. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

The technology you are probably looking for is [Java Web Start](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/)

Comment: I have a jar. I want execute only that, don't want any software dependency. So will this work? Also will the link generated from web start be accessible globally?

Comment: I tried deploying my jar using web start. It is working fine for my local system :).. I was missing signing of the jar. That's why it didnt work earlier.  Thank you. Now I move my jar and html file to a unix server. I want to test whether I can launch this jar from some other machine or not. But I'm nit able to figure out how should I run the html kept on server. I generated a url but it is opening winscp for me and nothing else is happening. Can you guide on that?